# What is the name of the musical sign consisting of two slanted parallel lines at the top of the staff?

Tags: notation, terminology

Today I was playing a piece of guitar music, and found this on the staff (inside a red circle):

[image]

What is the name of it and what does it do?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As always, I recommend bookmarking  [dolmetsch](http://www.dolmetsch.com/musicalsymbols.htm) .

Quoting:

> caesura (sing.), caesurae (pl.), fetura, 'tramlines', or 'railroad
>   tracks: usually placed on or above the top line of a staff or stave
>   (not to be confused with the 'simile' mark). A term derived from
>   poetry, caesura is a silent pause somewhere in the middle of a piece
>   of music

Comment: In other words this shows you like to take a breath.

Comment: @Nachmen not really.  A caesura is a major break;  a simple "breath" or quick pause is usually marked with an apostrophe.